# Unable to find the corner case I'm missing in a question I recently encountered

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, vector, std-pair

In yesterday's CodeChef contest I came across this problem in which I was able to write the code which was able to solve all the "normal" testcases, however, it failed when it came to a probable corner case that I seem to have missed.

The question is as follows:-

Dr. Chef is treating COVID-19 patients. There is a queue of N patients (numbered from patient 1 at the front of the queue to patient N at the back) outside his clinic. You, his assistant, found out that for each valid i, the i-th patient has an illness level Ai.

Chef treats patients based on their health, i.e. a patient with a higher illness level is always treated before any patients with a lower illness level. Chef is also fair, so he treats patients with an equal illness level based on their position in the queue, i.e. a patient ahead in the queue is always treated before a patient with the same illness level that is further behind in the queue.

The first patient to be treated has to wait an hour for Chef to set up his equipment. Treating each patient also takes an hour, and Chef always starts treating the next patient as soon as he is done with the current one.

The patients are a bit impatient. As Chef's assistant, for each patient, find out how long (in hours) this patient needs to wait before Chef starts treating this patient.

Input

The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.

The first line of each test case contains a single integer N.

The second line contains N space-separated integers A1,A2,…,AN.

Output

For each test case, print a single line containing N space-separated integers. For each valid i, the i-th of these integers should be the time the i-th patient needs to wait.

Constraints

1≤T≤5

1≤N≤105

1≤Ai≤1,000 for each valid i

Example Input

4

5

2 3 5 3 4

3

2 2 2

6

2 10 3 3 2 10

4

8 9 8 9

Example Output

5 3 1 4 2

1 2 3

5 1 3 4 6 2

3 1 4 2

Explanation

Example case 1: Patient number 3 has the highest illness level. Therefore, this patient just waits an hour for Chef to set up his equipment and gets treated immediately after. Patient number 5 has the next highest illness level, so they go next. They need to wait an hour for patient 3 to be treated. In total, patient 5 has to wait 2 hours. After that, both patients 2 and 4 have an equal illness level, but patient 2 is ahead in the queue, so patient 2 goes next, followed by patient 4, and then finally patient 1.

Example case 2: All three patients have the same illness level, so they are treated according to their position in the queue. Patient 1 goes first, followed by patient 2, and then patient 3.

Example case 3: Patients at positions 2 and 6 in the queue have the highest illness level 10. The patient at position 2 is ahead in the queue, so this patient is treated first, and then the patient at position 6 is treated. After this, the patients at positions 3 and 4 in the queue have the next highest illness level, so the patient at position 3 is treated next, followed by the patient at position 4. Similarly, afterwards, the patient at position 1 is treated, and then the patient at position 5 is treated.

Example case 4: Patients at positions 2 and 4 in the queue have the highest illness level 9, so the patient at position 2 is treated first, followed by the patient at position 4, then the patient at position 1 and finally the patient at position 3.

**Approach**

I approached the problem by storing elements Ai and index i in a vector of pairs and then sorting the vector according to Ai's to be able to access the highest levels of illness together in a sorted manner. I then started assigning hours from the first element of given Ai's in the range [1, 1000] in a descending order (higher order of illness is treated first). I came up with the following code:-

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
typedef unsigned long long int intl;
using namespace std;

bool icompare(pair<intl, intl> p1, pair<intl, intl> p2) //function to compare first elements of the pairs
{
    return (p1.first < p2.first);
}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    cout.tie(NULL);

    intl t; //no. of testcases
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        intl n;
        cin >> n;
        intl arr[n], ans[n], ctr[1000] = {0}; //arr stores Ai, ans stores no. of hours i'th 
patient has to wait for and ctr[1000] keeps count of number of occurrences of each Ai

        vector<pair<intl, intl>> v; //vector of pairs to store Ai paired with its index in original array
        for (intl i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cin >> arr[i];
            v.push_back(make_pair(arr[i], i)); //making of vector of pairs 
            ctr[arr[i] - 1]++;    //counting occurrences of each Ai (0 base indexing)
        }

        sort(v.begin(), v.end(), icompare);  //sorting first (arr[n]) elements of the vector

        intl a = 0, hours = 1; // a is used to find out indices of occurences of the same Ai with the help of the array ctr[1000] and hours keeps count of number of patients

        for (intl i = 1000; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (hours == n + 1) // base case
            {
                break;
            }

            intl idxprev = n - a;  // index where (i + 1) started
            a += ctr[i - 1]; // updating a for i
            intl idx = n - a; // index where i starts

            if (idxprev == idx) // if there is no Ai for the number
            {
                continue;
            }

            for (intl j = idx; j < idxprev; j++)
            {
                ans[v[j].second] = hours; // accessing original index of Ai for N patients with the 
help of second element of the pair
                hours++; 
            }
        }
        for (intl i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cout << ans[i] << " "; // printing the hours for each patient
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code passes the given the sample input but it failed the whole of the question i.e. there was a corner case which I could not identify. I've been thinking for more than a couple of hours now and am unable to think of any such case. Could someone kindly help me with the problem?

Comment: you probably need `std::stable_sort`

Comment: @Alan Birtles, the use to std::stable_sort did pass the test, thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

From the problem statement:

> Chef is also fair, so he treats patients with an equal illness level based on their position in the queue,

You have to preserve the initial ordering of elements with the same value, `std::sort` does not do that, you need to use `std::stable_sort` instead.